# Pagination function (loadMore function is overwriting the initial fetched)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, pagination

I'm trying to do a pagination function, but one problem is that when i try to 'load more' the new fetched is overwriting the initial ones (taking over the initial ones and makes the initial ones disappear), this is the code, how i'm fetching posts, first it should red the page number from the URL, and show the posts accordingly, if there is no page number it will show initial fetched posts, and there is a button to load more which uses the `loadMorePosts` function.

```
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
            const [initialPosts, setInitialPosts] = useState([]);
            const [additionalPosts, setAdditionalPosts] = useState([]);
        
        
        useEffect(() => {
          // Function to get the page number from the URL query string
          const getPageNumberFromURL = () => {
            const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
            const page = parseInt(params.get('page'));
            return isNaN(page) ? 1 : page;
          };
        
          const initialPage = getPageNumberFromURL();
          setCurrentPage(initialPage);
        
          // Fetch posts based on the current page
          const fetchPosts = async (page) => {
            try {
              const res = await axios.get(`/api/posts/${page}`);
              setInitialPosts(res.data);
              console.log("API Response (Initial Posts):", res.data);
              setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (err) {
              setAlertMsg({ fail: true, success: false, msg: `${translations.SomethingWentWrong}` });
              setIsLoading(false);
              console.log("Fetching Error (Initial Posts):", err);
            }
          };
        
          // Fetch posts when the component initializes or the URL parameter changes
          fetchPosts(initialPage);
        }, [location.search, translations]);

const loadMorePosts = () => {
  const nextPage = currentPage + 1;

  const fetchNextPage = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`/api/posts/${nextPage}`);
      setAdditionalPosts([...additionalPosts, ...res.data]);
      console.log("API Response (Additional Posts):", res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      setAlertMsg({ fail: true, success: false, msg: `${translations.SomethingWentWrong}` });
      console.log("Fetching Error (Additional Posts):", err);
    }
  };

  navigate(`/posts?page=${nextPage}`);
  setCurrentPage(nextPage); // Update the currentPage after navigation.
  fetchNextPage();
};
    
        // Filter and sort the posts based on the selected option
        const filteredAndSortedPosts = (postsToFilter) => {
    
          let sortedPosts = [...postsToFilter]; // Create a copy of the original posts array
          switch (selectedSortOption) {
            case `${translations.Latest}`:
              sortedPosts.sort();
              break;
            default:
              // Handle the default case here if needed
              break;
          } 
            return sortedPosts;
          };
          // Ends filter and sort the posts based on the selected option
    
    return (
    <div>
              filteredAndSortedPosts([...initialPosts, ...additionalPosts]).map((post) => (
                <div>
                  <Post
                  post={post} 
                  isLoading={isLoading} 
                  />
                </div>
              ))
    </div>
    )
```

I don't know where i went wrong, all i need is that when `additionalPosts` are fetched i don't want them to take over `initialPosts`, they should be next to each other.

Comment: I'm not to fluent with react, but I suppose `navigate("/foo/bar?baz=3")` does the same as clicking on a link? Thus, when you call `navigate` in your `loadMorePosts` the component is completely reinizialized from an empty state (ie like if you navigated to that site from somewhere else)

Comment: you are right, thank you